# How to globally catch unhandled Future errors?

Tags: dart, error-handling, async-await, future

Best practice is of course to always attach an error handler to a `Future` using `catchError()` (or using `await` and `try`/`catch`). But suppose I forgot, or suppose that this error is serious enough that we *want* it to crash the entire application (as we could do with synchronous exceptions), or that I want to log the error, or report it to some service like Crashlytics to make me aware of my sins.

Dart's `Future`s are practically the same as JavaScript's `Promise`s. In NodeJS, we can attach a handler to the global [`unhandledRejection` event](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection) to add custom behaviour.

Does Dart offer something similar? I looked through the async and `Future` documentation, but couldn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [`runZonedGuarded`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.3/dart-async/runZonedGuarded.html) static method. It will executing a given method in its own [`Zone`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.3/dart-async/Zone-class.html) which makes it possible to attach a method to handle any uncaught errors.

I have made a simple example here which shows what happens if a async error are throw without any handling of the error:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  runZonedGuarded(program, errorHandler);
}

Future<void> program() async {
  final file = File('missing_file.txt');
  await file.openRead().forEach(print);
}

void errorHandler(Object error, StackTrace stack) {
  print('OH NO AN ERROR: $error');
}
```

Which returns:

```
OH NO AN ERROR: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'missing_file.txt'...
```

Comment: Great answer! Can we also listen to `Isolate.current.errors`? https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-isolate/Isolate/errors.html

Comment: I have tried to get it to work but could not. My guess is not since this construction is made so if you have spawned an isolate, you can get the error which caused the crash of the isolate. So, if there are uncaught errors, the isolate will stop itself and then you cannot listen on the errors from the isolate itself.